# Google Play Services - taking up over 2GB and random crashing

Tags: google-play-services

I have already looked for an answer to this like thus:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22google+play+services%22  and
https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22google+play+services%22
This question seems to be the same, with no answer:  [Google Play Services takes up all internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150003/google-play-services-takes-up-all-internal-storage)

Recently, my Android (Galaxy S4, 16GB, Android 4.4.2), decided that Google Play Services needed to take up 1.5GB. I figured that it had somehow run amok. I followed instructions to delete the data. That seemed to be good for a while.

Well, just a week or so later, it downloaded 2GB+ (over the mobile data connection, eating up more than my monthly allocation). It is now 2.3GB. I suspect that it would take more, but the phone is saying it is out of space.

So, deleting the data didn't work.
I can't uninstall Google Play Services; I can try to tell it to revert, but it can't because the package is an active device administrator. But, it doesn't show up in the device administrator settings list.

I've looked in the folder, and it looks like it has an email file and an email log. These are 500MB+ each.

Every now and then, Google Play Services (and sometimes "Settings") will crash.

Can I fix this? Can I at least stop it? If I can't stop it, can I tell it to only use Wifi and not mobile data?